# How to wrap a table's tr in React as a child

Tags: reactjs, components

How do I wrap the {this.props.children} in the Father component?

Obviousely, div is not allowed. But have to wrap it.

Now I give more details about the problem. Basically, I'd like to have a Father Component which is able to fetch data and change its child to render different views in different situation. This is to display a table, the child is the table's row. I'd like to use the same data to display something else. 
Hope this is clear to express the problem.

```
Child = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return (
      <tr>
        <td> {this.props.name} </td>
        <td> {this.props.age} </td>
        <td> {this.props.address} </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
});    

Father = React.createClass({
  fetchData(){
    ...
  },
  render(){
    //how to wrap here? <div> is not allowed
    {this.props.children}
  }
});

GrandFather = React.createClass({
  renderSomething(){
    return this.props.persons.map((p) => {
      return ( <Father> 
                 <Child>
               </Father>
      )
    });
  },
  render(){
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Age  </th>
            <th> Address </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderSomething()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  }
});
```

Final update

---

Looks like there is no way wrap a  in a React Component. I thought there might have been some HTML magic I dont know. 
Eventually I just changed the code structure. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is too theoretical, you should provide a more concrete example. With your current code:

- The `Father` class does effectively nothing, so you can just drop it and your code will be fine.
- `renderSomething()` is IMHO never executed, assuming `GrandFather.render()` as an entry point.

Regarding your theoretical question:

- No, `render()` has to return one element, no more, no less. So you can't have a `render()` that just returns array of elements.

---

Looking at your updated question...

You can move `<tbody>` from `GrandFather` to `Father` and use that for wrapping. A `<table>` can contain multiple `<tbody>` sections.

Comment: I have added more code to clarify the problem. It really boils down to how to wrap a table's row <tr> element.

Comment: But by this way, the cell looks differently.

Comment: That seems to be a different problem related to the styling of your table.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands you're just returning an empty div so you won't be having any problems. You're going to want to move some other things around but...

Is the answer you're looking as straightforward as having the Father div be the table tags?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. Now I edited the question and added more code. I'd like the Father component as a data source component, so it can change its child to display different views.

Comment: I would try to do away with the Father component, if possible, as it adds what probably is an unnecessary level of complexity. When and how are you trying to call Fetchdata()? Could you call it directly in the child components and then in renderSomething just return the Child components (this would be a valid jsx return object) ?